# Dynamic programming MPILOT

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem on spoj ([MPILOT](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MPILOT/)).

I have understood that it's a dynamic programing problem,and i had tried it also but its giving me a wrong answer. my approach is like get the salary difference of pilot and assistant and sort it in decreasing order and then for`0 - N/2` add as `assistant` and for `N/2+1 - N` add as `pilot` and output the `sum`. but the problem is coming with the age condition that pilot has to be older than assistant.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#define lint long long

using namespace std;

struct pilot {
lint pilotsal;
lint assistantsal;
lint diff;
};

bool compare (pilot p1, pilot p2)
{
 return (p1.diff > p2.diff);
}

int main()
{
lint c,n,i;
lint sum=0,max=0;
 cin >> n;
vector <pilot> pilots(n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> pilots[i].pilotsal >> pilots[i].assistantsal;
    pilots[i].diff= pilots[i].pilotsal-pilots[i].assistantsal;
}
 sum = max = pilots[0].assistantsal;
 sort(pilots.begin()+1,pilots.end(),compare);
for(i=1;i<=n/2-1;i++)
{
    sum+=pilots[i].assistantsal;
}

for(i=n/2;i<n;i++)
{
    sum+=pilots[i].pilotsal;
}
   cout << sum << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

please give me some hint. how to check for the age condition for the problem.

Comment: please do help me with some hint as i am really looking to solve this.

Comment: thanks for the edit, and can you please help me with it.

Comment: I am trying the problem right now, but I can't assure anything.

Comment: it fine if its done with you then please help me a bit also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an hour trying to solve this problem using "dynamic programming" I concluded that this is not the appropriate way, but the problem is not solved yet. Many greedy ideas came to my mind but greedy is not good in most cases.

At the end I couldn't solve this problem, but since the problem is interesting I did search the solution and here is what I understand of the solution:

The pilots are sorted in ascending order:

- The very first pilot must to be an assistant
- The very last pilot must to be a captain

The worst solution is when we pay all the pilots(captains and assistants) as captains. This will be our first solution and we'll try to reduce this amount to the minimum.

The **saving** we can get from turning a captain to an assistant is `Pilot.CaptainWage - Pilot.AssistantWage`.

The problem turns easy because only the minimum pay is required and not the  grouping itself.

```
1. Set the first pilot as assistant
2. Insert each pilot in a list from the second to the last, and for every 2 new elements in the list
  // One pilot can be turned to an assistant only if remains at least another older pilot
  2.1 Select the pilot who contribute with the maximum saving so far
  2.2 Rest the saving of the previous step to our original solution
  2.3 Remove the pilot from the list
3. Print our new solution
```

**Note:** You need an efficient data structure to obtain the pilot with the maximum saving in a fast way, maybe a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

See if you can get to the solution with this. I don't post the link to the actual solution because is better if you try it by yourself first:).

Comment: thanks i will try it by myself and if there comes any problem then i will come to you.